# Passing value between NSTabView

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nstabview

I try to do a simple program in cocoa, a NSTabVew with 2 items, in the first item I set a content to a string var, in the second tab I display this value. I create two Object class (Prima and Seconda), than I add 2 object in IB setting like Prima and Seconda

Prima.m

```
- (IBAction) salva:(id) sender{  
    nome = [field stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",nome);
}
```

Seconda.m

```
- (IBAction) visualizza:(id) sender{
    NSString *dato;
    Prima *prima = [[Prima alloc] init];
    dato = prima.nome;
    [label setStringValue:dato];
}
```

when I run the program I get this error:

```
2011-10-03 11:42:43.511 Prova[44622:707] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1564
2011-10-03 11:42:43.511 Prova[44622:707] Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
2011-10-03 11:42:43.513 Prova[44622:707] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d497986 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff90ed9d5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d4977ba +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8cce914f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 169
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff88957685 -[NSCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:] + 160
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff889575df -[NSCell _objectValue:forString:] + 19
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff88957545 -[NSCell setStringValue:] + 41
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff88a58039 -[NSControl setStringValue:] + 115
    8   Prova                               0x0000000100001365 -[Seconda visualizza:] + 133
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d48711d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a3f852 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a3f784 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 88
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a3f6af -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 137
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a3eb7a -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2014
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff88abe57c -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 489
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a3d786 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 786
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff88a0866e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6280
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff889a0f19 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5665
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8893742b -[NSApplication run] + 548
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff88bb552a NSApplicationMain + 867
    20  Prova                               0x0000000100000f92 main + 34
    21  Prova                               0x0000000100000f64 start + 52
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

where is the error for you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that dato is nil, which (based on what you've given us) is probably because things aren't hooked up right in the XIB. Without more information I can't say more.

Comment: Here you can download the application, I think you can understand better than what I can write :D www.allmyapp.net/wp-content/Prova.zip

Comment: probably I understand the problem....is the Action, if I init my class with some data, for example nome = @"test" I can see my var on Seconda class. How can I pass a variable of a text field with an Action??